# Is density() function counts as probability density function?

Tags: r, plot, probability-density

In my assignment, the instructor asked us to plot a histogram in R, then add the probability distribution function on it. So I used the density() function and did something like this:

[image]

Did I do it correctly?

My code is:

```
df <- read.table("values.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
hist(df$first, freq=FALSE, col="lightblue", main="", xlab="", ylab="")
lines(density(df$first))
```

Comment: you have implemented it correctly for base graphics 

Comment: Note that the term "probability distribution function" can sometimes refer to either the PDF or the CDF

Comment: @mickey so what I did is acceptable as pdf?

Comment: @J.T. Yes. Density() gives you an estimate of the pdf. You can play with some of the parameters in density() and get differently shaped pdfs. So while it may not be the "true" pdf, it's a good enough estimate. My comment was meant to be more nitpicky than needed.